# Trouble with pagination while scraping NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, cheerio

I am writing a little script that scrapes some information from public directories. I have it being saved to CSV but I'm having trouble with automating the pagination.

My Source is:

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const request = ('request');
const otcsv = require('objects-to-csv');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

// URL To scrape
const baseURL = 'xx';
const searchURL = 'xxx';

// scrape info
const getCompanies = async () => {
    // Pagination test 

    for(let index = 0; index <= 2; index = index + 1) {
        const html = await request.get("xxx" + index);
        const $ = await cheerio.load(html);
        console.log("Loading Pages....");
        // console.log("At page number" + index);
        // end pagination test
        const htmls = await rp(baseURL + searchURL);
        const businessMap = cheerio('a.business-name', htmls).map(async (i, e) => {
            const link = baseURL + e.attribs.href;
            const innerHtml = await rp(link);
            const emailAddress = cheerio('a.email-business', innerHtml).prop('href');
            const name = e.children[0].data || cheerio('h1', innerHtml).text();
            const phone = cheerio('p.phone', innerHtml).text();

            return {
                emailAddress: emailAddress ? emailAddress.replace('mailto:', '') : '',
                //  link,
                name,
                phone,
            }

        }).get();
        return Promise.all(businessMap);
    }
};

// save to CSV
getCompanies()
  .then(result => {
    const transformed = new otcsv(result);
    return transformed.toDisk('./output.csv');
  })
  .then(() => console.log('SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED THE WEB SCRAPING SAMPLE'));
```

The error that's appearing is *request.get isn't a function.*

**EDIT**

Second part to this question is located here: [Nodejs Scraper isn't moving to next page(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363001/nodejs-scraper-isnt-moving-to-next-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.get` should be `rp.get`, since `request` module does not return a `Promise`.

In any case you're getting the error, because you're not `require`ing `request`, but just assigning a `string` to `request` variable:

```
const request = ('request');
```

Change it to:

```
const request = require('request');
```

Since you're working with Promises, I recommend to just require, `request-promise`

```
const request = require('request-promise');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marcos, now I’m having the trouble of getting it to go to the next page, any ideas

Comment: Great, I didn't realise i could link to 2 posts together, the second post is up here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363001/nodejs-scraper-isnt-moving-to-next-pages