# Nodejs Scraper isn't moving to next page(s)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

Hey guys this is a follow on from my other question, i have created a Nodejs Scraper that doesnt seem to want to go through the pages, it stays on the first. my source code is below

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const request = require('request');
const otcsv = require('objects-to-csv');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

//URL To scrape
const baseURL = 'xxx';
const searchURL = 'xxxx';

//scrape info
const getCompanies = async () => {
  // Pagination test

  for (let index = 1; index <= 20; index = index + 1) {
    const html = await rp.get(baseURL + searchURL + index);
    const $ = await cheerio.load(html);
    console.log("Loading Pages....");
    console.log("At page number " + index);
    // end pagination test
    //const htmls = await rp(baseURL + searchURL);
    const businessMap = cheerio('a.business-name', html).map(async (i, e) => {
      const link = baseURL + e.attribs.href;
      const innerHtml = await rp(link);
      const emailAddress = cheerio('a.email-business', innerHtml).prop('href');
      const name = e.children[0].data || cheerio('h1', innerHtml).text();
      const phone = cheerio('p.phone', innerHtml).text();

      return {
        //  link,
        name,
        emailAddress: emailAddress ? emailAddress.replace('mailto:', '') : '',
        phone,
      }

    }).get();
    return Promise.all(businessMap);
  }
};
console.log("Finished Scraping.... Now Saving!")
//save to CSV
getCompanies()
  .then(result => {
    const transformed = new otcsv(result);
    return transformed.toDisk('./output.csv');
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Scrape Complete :D '));
```

As you can see I have tried a few different ways to make this happen so any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say without the urls. One thing to keep in mind is that cheerio doesn't return promises. Only rp.get() is returning promises here. Also you should be using `$` inside the main loop.